# Meteor js, body.helper function getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor

I'm playing around with  MeteorJS, and im trying to make a function in the Template.body.helpers to grab my img tags in an array

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.body.helpers({
    place: function(){

      var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
      console.log(images)
      console.log(typeof images)
      for(k in images)
        console.log(k)
      return images
  }
}
```

[] i get this opject that i cant access

object is returned from the typeof

the console (k) shows
 length,
 item, and
 namedItem

but if i use the console i can get my two images and use them, unlike this code...

and this is the output in the browser 
       [object HTMLCollection]

All i want to do is collect my images in an array and then get the alt tag

```
[]
 0: img.toon
 1: img.toon
 length: 2 
proto: HTMLCollection
```

this is the object i get from console.log(images). but if i try images[0] i get     undefined

thanks for any help

So i added a button with a click event to fire the same code and i get my array of images as expected...  if i wrap the original code in document onload function it doesn't appear to run.

Comment: 1) You can edit your post, you don't need to add information in the comments. 2) Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you should put your main code inside `Template.body.onRendered` since you need to wait when the DOM is ready.

Something like this should works, if you are trying to collect `alt` attribute values:

```
Template.body.onRendered(function() {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var imagesAlts = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < images.length; k++) {
    imagesAlts.push(images[k].getAttribute('alt'));
  }
  Session.set('imagesAlts', imagesAlts);
  return;
});

Template.body.helpers({

  place: function() {
    var imagesAlts = Session.get('imagesAlts')
    console.log(imagesAlts);
    return imagesAlts;
  }

});
```

*Note*: you can use `document.images` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('img')`.

Comment: Thank you Andrea, I had over looked the onRendered function.